# Defining and calling a function in sagetex not working as expected

Tags: errors, pdf, warnings, undefined, sagetex

In the code below I use `sagetex` to define a function `f(n)` that returns the nth fibonacci number. I used `sagesilent` so that the contents of the function are not typeset. Then I call and print the value of `f(10)` using `\sagestr`. However I get a warning `LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.` and the value is replaced with `??`. Why is latex unable to find the value although I clearly defined it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}

\begin{sagesilent}
def f(n):
    if n==1 or n==2:
        return 1
    else:
        return f(n-1)+f(n-2)
\end{sagesilent}

$f(10)=\sagestr{f(10)}$

\end{document}
```

Wanted output:

```
f(10) = 55
```

Actual output:

```
f(10) = ??
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is somewhat off topic. But why to use an external software when we have TeX:

```
\def\fib#1{\ifnum\numexpr#1<3 1\else \the\numexpr \fib{#1-1}+\fib{#1-2}\relax\fi}

$f(10)=\fib{10}$
```

Answer (score 0):

The message was `LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.` and the result was `??` for your output. Since you have only called Sage once the mistake is in the line: `$f(10)=\sagestr{f(10)}$`. The argument for  `\sagestr` has to be a string, such as "55", and not a number 55. Since your function outputs a number you want`$f(10)=\sage{f(10)}$`. Changing your code shows it running without issue:
[image]

If, for some reason, you want to keep the line `$f(10)=\sagestr{f(10)}$` then you can provided you make the function return the string "55". This can be done by wrapping your answer with `str()` as in `return str(f(n-1)+f(n-2))`.

The difference between numerical versus string output is clearer by noting `$\sage{f(10)}$` is `55` but `\sagestr{"f(10)"}` is `f(10)`.